# While sending data from controller to view it gives an error as function() not found

Tags: php, cakephp

I am learning CakePHP.I want to pass fetched data from controller to view page.

Controller (ProfileController)

```
public function download_result($poll_id)
{
    $this->_checkVipSession();

    $this->Poll->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('PollAnswer' => array('foreignKey' =>'poll_id'))), false); 
    $condition = "Poll.id = ".$poll_id." AND Poll.isdeleted = '0' ";

    $poll_info = $this->Poll->find('first',array('conditions'=>$condition));

    $this->set('poll_info',$poll_info);

    Configure::write('debug', '2');
}
```

View(download_result.ctp)

```
<?php
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($poll_info);
?>
```

It gives an error like :

```
Missing View

Error: The view for ProfileController::download_result() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: /home/webbrain/public_html/cake/app/views/profile/download_result.ctp

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_view.ctp
```

So how can I resolve it?

**Note :** I have used CakePHP version 1.3.13

Comment: the error message explains it all: are you sure your .ctp file is in the right folder and has the right name? Check it twice. Also: if you're learning cake from the beginning why starting with 1.3 and not 3.x serie?

Comment: @arilia now its working.But its display **CakePHP: the rapid development php framework**. So how can I remove it?

Comment: You have to change the default layout. But I suggest reading the whole manual, and consider learning cake3 instead of cake 1 if you can.

Comment: @arilia Yes, but i have to work on it because this project built in 1.3.13.And my role is to develope remaining issue.

Comment: @arilia  Thanks,its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Place your view download_result.ctp into cake/app/views/profile/

Now, I would recommend for you to stop using such an older version and start learning with versions 3.x, the newest would be better, [Cakephp 3.2](http://cakephp.org/).

It's not necessary to start with an old version, specially because the changes between them are big (and because new stuff is almost better).

Comment: My view file extension was wrong.Now its working. And I have assign this project that is built in 1.3.13 version of cakephp.

Comment: That's a bad assignment, you should say to whoever assigned it. One should always try to use state of the art software.